# pyspark: how to remove escape character from column values when doing collect_list()?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv that needs to be converted to json and grouped by a group number (with 2 records per group), and written back as json file, with each group's json data in each file and have 1 record per file.
Structure of CSV:

```
"member_id"|"DOB"|"name"
"23343"|"1980-06-06"|"Alice"
"63435"|"1985-07-06"|"Bob"
"23577"|"1990-12-31"|"Max"
```

I am able to convert the csv to json string, and create a group number:

```
def mapToJson(instance):
    myObj = MyCustomObject()
    ....
    ..
    _json = myObj.as_json()
    myJson = {}
    myJson["fullUrl"] = 'urn:uuid'
    myJson["resource"] = _json
    return myJson
    
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").option("header","true").load(filepathsrc)
rddJson = df1.rdd.map(lambda instance: Row(json.dumps(mapToJson(instance))))   #Converting csv to JSON
df = rddJson.toDF()

df.show(10, False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                             _1                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23343","DOB":"1980-06-06","name":"Alice"}} |
|{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"63435","DOB":"1985-07-06","name":"Bob"}}   |
|{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23577","DOB":"1990-12-31","name":"Max"}}   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

### Till above things looks good.

w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
df = df.withColumn("ROW_ID", row_number().over(w)) \
                   .withColumn("group_num",(row_number().over(Window.orderBy("ROW_ID"))-1) % 2 ) \
                   .withColumnRenamed("_1","DATA") \
                   .groupby(col("group_num")) \
                   .agg(collect_list(col("DATA")).alias("entry"),
                        collect_list(col("ROW_ID")).alias("ROW_ID")) \
                   .drop(col("group_num")) \
                   .drop(col("ROW_ID")) \
                   .withColumn("resourceType",lit("Bundle")) 

df.write.format("json").option("quote", "\u0000").mode('overwrite').option("maxRecordsPerFile",1).save(filepathtgt)
```

**The problem:**
The generated json file is having **"entry"** list column's data as a list of String and with escaped backslash character.

```
{"entry": ["{\"fullUrl\":\"urn:uuid\", \"resource\": {\"member_id\":\"23343\",\"DOB\":\"1980-06-06\",\"name\":\"Alice\"}}",
           "{\"fullUrl\":\"urn:uuid\", \"resource\": {\"member_id\":\"63435\",\"DOB\":\"1985-07-06\",\"name\":\"Bob\"}}",
           "{\"fullUrl\":\"urn:uuid\", \"resource\": {\"member_id\":\"23577\",\"DOB\":\"1990-12-31\",\"name\":\"Max\"}}"], 
 "resourceType": "Bundle"}
```

However I want my output file to be like:

```
{"entry": [{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23343","DOB":"1980-06-06","name":"Alice"}},
           {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"63435","DOB":"1985-07-06","name":"Bob"}},
           {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23577","DOB":"1990-12-31","name":"Max"}}], 
 "resourceType": "Bundle"}
```

i.e. when doing `collect_list()`, I need it array of json, not array of string, and not escaping the values.

**Update:**
I removed `json.dumps()`, but then the json's `:` is changing to `=` character, and the json structure is getting enclosed inside `"`:

```
{"entry": [{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=23343, DOB=1980-06-06, name=Alice}" },
           {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=63435, DOB=1985-07-06, name=Bob}" },
           {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=23577, DOB=1990-12-31, name=Max}" }], 
 "resourceType": "Bundle"}
```

i.e. the json value `"{member_id=23343, DOB=1980-06-06, name=Alice}"` for **key** `resource` is getting enclosed in double-quotes.

Modified the code and added `.selectExpr("cast(entry as string)entry")`, the dataframe content is looking good, but while writing to JSON file it is again inserting `"\"` for escaping:

```
df = df.withColumn("ROW_ID", row_number().over(w)) \
                   .withColumn("group_num",(row_number().over(Window.orderBy("ROW_ID"))-1) % 2 ) \
                   .withColumnRenamed("_1","DATA") \
                   .groupby(col("group_num")) \
                   .agg(collect_list(col("DATA")).alias("entry"),
                        collect_list(col("ROW_ID")).alias("ROW_ID")) \
                   .selectExpr("cast(entry as string)entry") \
                   .withColumn("resourceType",lit("Bundle")) 

df.show(10,False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|                                             entry                                            |  resourceType     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|[{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23343","DOB":"1980-06-06","name":"Alice"}}, |    Bundle         |
|{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"63435","DOB":"1985-07-06","name":"Bob"}}]    |                   |
|[{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": {"member_id":"23577","DOB":"1990-12-31","name":"Max"}}]   |    Bundle         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

How do i write to file without escape character ?

Comment: if you want a array of json, then don't transform your json in string ... the problem comes from `json.dumps`. why are you doing this ?

Comment: and btw, dataframe ==> rdd ==> dataframe is a terrible workflow

Comment: I tried removing `json.dumps` but the output has repalced `:` with `=`. like this: `{"entry": [{"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=23343, DOB=1980-06-06, name=Alice}" }, {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=63435, DOB=1985-07-06, name=Bob}" }, {"fullUrl":"urn:uuid", "resource": "{member_id=23577, DOB=1990-12-31, name=Max}" }],  "resourceType": "Bundle"}`

Comment: @aiman did you find a solution? I have the same problem while adding an array in the dataframe

Comment: @Bentech i left the team now, but i remember i additionally tried casting as string, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.